# Install snap() on wsl2 for flutter

Tags: flutter, command-line, wsl-2, snap

I have just started working on flutter SDK. In its installation(for linux) I found the following command

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

But it needed snapd to be installed on my computer(wsl). I have windows operating system but I work on WSL (version 2) for my development related activities so I was going through linux installation method. I am unable to find any resources to download snap on my wsl (and do not even know what snap actually is). Can anyone suggest any commands or methods so that I can following along further with [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path:%7E:text=can%20install%20Flutter.-,Install%20Flutter%20using%20snapd,-The%20easiest%20way) or anyother wy by which i can install flutter in wsl.

Also I tried downloading it manually but that downloads the flutter file over to windows and I also don't know if I could change the file location to wsl from windows. If it could be done this way then please tell.
If any further information is needed, then please tell :)

Comment: Snap requires Systemd under Ubuntu.  WSL didn't originally include Systemd (and thus Snap) support, but it recently added it.  See the question [Enable Systemd in WSL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400999/enable-systemd-in-wsl-2) where there's a Community Wiki on how to enable it.

Comment: However, I should have asked if you are actually using Ubuntu.  It's possible to use non-Ubuntu distributions under WSL2, although Ubuntu is the default.  If you are using a different distribution, you'll need to follow [the directions](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd) for installing Snap on your system.