# Kafka service does not start

Tags: apache-kafka, systemd, wsl-2

I am trying to install Kafka following a tutorial from DigitalOcean.com [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-20-04).

I am doing this on Windows WSL2 with Ubuntu. So, after creating the `zookeeper.service` and `kafka.service` as per the tutorial, I do this command (the tutorial uses  `sudo systemctl start kafka` instead), following advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate):

```
sudo service kafka start
```

I received :

```
kafka: unrecognized service
```

When I do `service --status-all` to see if kafka is in the list, it is not there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lack of support in WSL for systemd

[why systemd is disabled in WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579342/why-systemd-is-disabled-in-wsl)

Comment: I was at step 4 and got stuck at starting the kafka service. I found another article [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/#install-java) that works completely. So I will close this thread. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Also, the command ```sudo service kafka enable``` yields the same error ```kafka: unrecognized service```. Same for ```zookeeper```.

Comment: The suggested solution is to directly execute the start of the service, thats what unit files are for... but I guess if you are just looking to make it run for development it is ok, the real answe is that you probably missing the /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service

Comment: I do have the file ```/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service``` and ```/etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service```. In both articles, the steps require these two files to be created. I just don't know why it does not recognize both services in the DigitalOcean article.

Comment: Try the following: systemctl daemon-reload , and then the start again

Comment: I got this error ```System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.``` when running that command.

Comment: Instead of using

sudo systemctl start kafka

use:

sudo /etc/init.d/kafka start

as of right now seems there not have systemd in WSL

Comment: Seems lack of systemd in WSL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579342/why-systemd-is-disabled-in-wsl