# Why doesn't WSL create /run/user/${uid} directory?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I wonder why there is no directory like `/run/user/1000` when using WSL2 with Ubuntu 18.04 image?

How can I fix this (if possible)?

Answer (score 2):

The user runtime directory `/run/user/$UID` is a tmpfs created and mounted by systemd on user login.

Since WSL instances do not support systemd, there is no daemon that creates this directory. This also implies that systemd/systemctl commands do not run on your WSL boxes. Please refer to [why systemd is disabled in WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579342/why-systemd-is-disabled-in-wsl) for more details and discussions on how to hack systemd into your WSL box.